# how to fill out the table with next values in array with one button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

say that my array value is as follows. var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
how can I make it so that clicking the button can display the item in array one after another in different boxes?

for example..first click = array[0]
second click = array[1] ...and so on.

below is my code so far. every time the button is clicked, it will only print all the values in array one by one to the same table.

```
<tr>
    <td><p id="result2"></p></td>
    <td><p id="result3"></p></td>
    ....
</tr>

<button onclick="clickBowl()">Bowl</button>
```

JS:

```
var k = 0;

function clickBowl() {
    x = document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = frameArr[k++];
}
```

Comment: When you say different boxes do you mean you want a new TD added to the TR to show the next value in the array?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan  please see my code so far. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ed43L0ts/).  everytime I click, "Bowl", it adds the next array value to the same TD. I need it so that first click adds array value[0] to "Frame 1"  , click again adds array value[1] to "Frame 2"...etc

Comment: What is Frame 1 and Frame 2? It sounds like you want to add a new TD on every button click?

Comment: yes, that is correct. so array value[0] should go under Frame 1 on click, and next click should add array value[1] under Frame 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<tr id="results"></tr>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0, myArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7];
    function clickBowl() {
        if (i > myArr.length) return;
        var child = document.createElement("td");
        child.innerHTML = myArr[i++];
        document.getElementById("results").appendChild(child);
    }
</script>
```

That way, you define a global scope var `i` that each time you click on the bowl, you will add one after you use it in order to get the value with that key from your array and append a `td` child to your results row.

Comment: You also need to check that i is not greater than the size of the array

Comment: Instead of I you could also use `document.getElementById("results").cells.length`.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Taxicalas answer is correct but i'd like to post this jQuery version:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$(function(){
    $("button")
    .on("click", function(){
        if(array.length === 0) return;
        $("table").append("<tr><td>" + array[0] + "</td></tr>");
        array.shift();        
    });
});
```

The shift method of the array removes the first element.

https://jsfiddle.net/ztkdvz3m/

Answer (score 0):

In your case it will be something like this:

```
var k = 0;

function clickBowl() {
    document.getElementById("result" + ++k).innerHTML = frameArr[k - 1];
}
```

Note, that you need one more value for the last slot (Frame 10).

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/ed43L0ts/1/

Answer (score 0):

Building on previous answer

```
<table>
    <tr id="tableRow">
    </tr>
</table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0, array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6];

    function clickBowl() {
        var currentValue = array[i++];
        var tableData = document.createElement("td");
        tableData.innerHTML = "<p id=" + currentValue + ">" + currentValue + "</p>";
        document.querySelector("#tableRow").appendChild(tableData);
       }

    array.forEach (clickBowl);    
</script>
```